# Rollback transactions of another stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have 3 stored procedures called after each other and independent of each other.

Now, if the 2nd stored procedure fails, then I want to roll back the transactions of the 1st stored procedure. And if 3rd fails then I want to roll back transactions of the above 2 procedures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL Server has no notion of nested transactions, so a single `ROLLBACK` will in fact abort everything, except that, if you do not issue as many `ROLLBACK`s as there are `BEGIN TRANSACTIONS`, you will get an error to that effect (but all work is still undone). To a first approximation, for most scenarios it is sufficient to do a `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the top of every procedure so transactions are aborted at the first failure. In other words, follow [this pattern](https://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern). For even more fancy scenarios, read the rest of that series.

Comment: Note that if the procedures are called externally by a client, not each other, and they're supposed to be atomic together, it is that client's responsibility to start a transaction (and commit/abort as necessary). In this case the procedures do not have to do anything with transactions themselves, though if the general error handling patterns are followed things will work whether or not they do.